# How to handle multiple file types (i.e. ANSI, UTF-8, etc) Java

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to write to a new CSV file(using a specific file encoding [i.e. UTF-8]) using an uploaded CSV file(using InputStream in Java) and passing it to another function with the file location.

If I convert any file to UTF-8, regardless of the encoding, will I lose data? If so, how can I preserve the characters that may be at risk of changing?

```
boolean success = false;

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    uploadedFileLocation));

            //OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(uploadedFileLocation), "UTF-8");

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
//              osw.write(read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            /*osw.flush();
            osw.close();*/
            uploadedInputStream.close();

            success = true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create InputStream (Buffered, File, whatever), you can give the charset...
The reader will convert into UTF, that is used in Java.
When you create an OuputStream , it's the same thing. Give the encoding and the writer will convert values.

In fact, from ISO -> UTF, you're safe. The inverse operation is false if you try to write a character that not exists in the destination charset. Something like... (take the stream hierarchy you like)

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("")), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("file"), Charset.forName("UTF8")));
```

Comment: It seems that I am losing data when I convert the file from ANSI to UTF-8, any particular reason why this may be happening? Is there a way I can preserve the data?

Comment: Should not happend. Cannot explain you that :s